I'm getting 60-130V of output from a 5V voltage regulator. Does anyone know what went wrong?
I made a 5V power supply, but when I connected my multimeter probes to the output lines of the supply it read 60-130V. the voltage after the rectifier should be around 18-19V. If anyone can give a explanation of what went wrong it would be greatly appreciated.



We don't know how you built it or how you measured it and with what you measured it. Your circuit looks OK as drawn but we can't know if what you built matches your drawing. Did you use multimeter, scope, or what meter, and how you connected it where (red lead, black lead, probe tip, probe ground) and what were the scope/meter settings (AC, DC, range, etc).

Very low battery in your multimeter?

A photograph of your circuit and test setup might be very helpful in getting you an answer to your problem.

@Justme I connected my multimeter's red lead to the 5V wire and the black lead to the GND wire. I set the voltage to DC 20V, then I tried DC 200V.

Try measuring with a different meter.

Or try measuring something like a 9V battery with the same meter.

@evildemonic here you go https://misom.org/IMG_1589.jpg

@MOSFET I tried measuring 5V from my bench power supply and my multimeter read 60V, i'll try changing the battery

@catandmoose please add the picture to the question ... a comment is not the place for it

Yep, as winny suspected, my multimeter battery was low. Thank you everyone for your help, have a nice day.
